# Data Table lazy load with pagination not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am trying to load some rows from large amount of data but I am not able to do that.
I have tried both deferloading and deferrender in all forms.
Please Help me

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example').DataTable( {
        // responsive: true,
        // "stateSave": true,
        // "dom": '<"top"flip>rt<"bottom"ip><"clear">',
        "bProcessing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "deferLoading": 5,
        "ajax": {
            url:"themes/garland/server-processing.php",
            type:"POST"

        }, 

        select: true
    });
});
```

Comment: what error you are getting? Did you check the json structure?

Comment: I am not getting an error all records are loading first. which i don't want I want  some records to be loaded first to process faster. So my user don't wait much.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code which loads some set of data, after clicked **Load More** button, another set of rows will be inserted..

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
   var table = $('#example').DataTable({
      dom: 'frt',
      ajax: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/qgcu',
      drawCallback: function(){
         // If there is some more data
         if($('#btn-example-load-more').is(':visible')){
            // Scroll to the "Load more" button
            $('html, body').animate({
               scrollTop: $('#btn-example-load-more').offset().top
            }, 1000);
         }

         // Show or hide "Load more" button based on whether there is more data available
         $('#btn-example-load-more').toggle(this.api().page.hasMore());
      }      
   });
 
   // Handle click on "Load more" button
   $('#btn-example-load-more').on('click', function(){  
      // Load more data
      table.page.loadMore();
   });
});
```

```css
.dt-more-container {
   text-align:center;
   margin:2em 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.15/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://gyrocode.github.io/jquery-datatables-pageLoadMore/1.0.0/js/dataTables.pageLoadMore.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.15/datatables.min.css"/>
<h3><a href="https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-load-more-button/" target="_blank">jQuery DataTables: "Load more" button</a></h3>

<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>

<div class="dt-more-container">
   <button id="btn-example-load-more" style="display:none">Load More</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Want to have pagination please help me with that